# How to $set sub-sub-array value in MongoDB by pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50cda9741d41c81da6000002"),
    "template_name" : "common_MH",
    "role" : "MH",
    "options" : [
        {
            "sections" : [
                {
                    "tpl_option_name" : "test321",
                    "tpl_option_type" : "string",
                    "tpl_default_value" : "test321"
                }
            ],
            "tpl_section_name" : "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

could I modify tpl_default_value in options.$.section.$.tpl_option_name = 'test321'?
I already try too times, but I can't solve.
please assist me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad schema for doing these kinda of updates, there is a JIRA for multi-level positional operator however it is not yet done: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Ideally you either have to update this client side and then atomically set that section of the array:

```
$section = {
    "tpl_option_name" : "test321",
    "tpl_option_type" : "string",
    "tpl_default_value" : "test321"    
};

db.col.update({}, {$set: {options.$.sections.1: $section}})
```

Or you need to change your schema. Does the sections really need to be embedded? I noticed that you have a `tpl_section_name` in the top level but then you are nesting sections within that, it sounds more logical that only one section should be there.

That document would be easier to update.

Comment: thanks, you means that the sections are independent in another collection?

Comment: Yea basically unfortunately.